# Is it possible to be asked to add Metadata when uploading using Explorer

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, open-with-explorer

Files that are being uploaded to ouR Document Library using the Explorer end up being not filled with Metadata.

Is there a way for the users to be asked to add the metadata when uploading using the explorer.

Ideal would be a window to open up asking them to fill the Metadata.

Or is there any other option to tackle this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no, there's no way to have fields fill out unless there is some other mechanism that does it.  For instance a workflow that can parse the file name to get field values or an Event Receiver that can parse the file name for field values.  Simply dragging and dropping into an explorer window does not trigger a popup that will allow entry of fields.

Comment: You can use Document Set and which will inherits the metadata from the folder and if users have latest Office they could fill the metadata through Property Panel.

Comment: We are trying to go away from using folders and  the Property Panel seems like a good option but we want some more user friendly. Some sort of notifications would be the best approach